# Default value in dropdown menu (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I wish to set the default value in a dropdown menu to the middle one (not the first).

I use dropdowns on my site for visitors to choose one of three / four / five sizes of a product.

The JavaScript is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#option1').show();
    $('#selectMe').change(function () {
        $('.group').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    })
});
```

The other code is:

```
<select id="selectMe">
    <option value="option1">S</option>
    <option value="option2">M</option>
    <option value="option3">L</option>
</select>
```

User chooses a value, and then the BUY button changes accordingly. Thus ...

```
<div>
    <div id="option1" class="group">Button for size S</div>
    <div id="option2" class="group">Button for size M</div>
    <div id="option3" class="group">Button for size L</div>
</div>
```

This works great, but in this instance, I want M to be the default, and not S (there are three sizes here, but sometimes there are more).

Comment: Do you mean you want the button for the selected option to be visible and the other two buttons to be hidden? If so, that's not how it should be done. There should be only one BUY button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use following snippets:

1. With jQuery

   ```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var $select = $('#selectMe');

       $select.val("option2");//initial value
       $("[id=" + $select.val() + "]").show()
           .siblings().hide();

       $select.change(function () {
           $("[id=" + $select.val() + "]").show()
               .siblings().hide();
       });
   });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <select id="selectMe">
           <option value="option1">S</option>
           <option value="option2">M</option>
           <option value="option3">L</option>
       </select>

       <div>
           <div id="option1" class="group">Button for size S</div>
           <div id="option2" class="group">Button for size M</div>
           <div id="option3" class="group">Button for size L</div>
       </div>
   ```
2. Or, You can do it through pure JavaScript

   ```js
   var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectMe")
   selectBox.selectedIndex = parseInt(selectBox.length / 2);

   selectBox.onchange = function () {
       changeButton(this.value);
   }

   changeButton(selectBox.value);

   function changeButton(val) {
       console.log(val)
       var i = -1, elements = document.querySelectorAll('[class=group]');
       while (elements[++i]) {
           console.log(elements[i]);
           elements[i].style.display = (elements[i].id == val) ? "block" : "none";
       }
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <select id="selectMe">
       <option value="option1">S</option>
       <option value="option2">M</option>
       <option value="option3">L</option>
   </select>

   <div>
       <div id="option1" class="group">Button for size S</div>
       <div id="option2" class="group">Button for size M</div>
       <div id="option3" class="group">Button for size L</div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Thank you. This works great, but it does not affect the buy button. In this instance, when the page is loaded, "M" is in the dropbown, but "Button for size S" is still displayed.

Comment: I suggest two way. 1.with jquery and 2. with pure javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make a `selected` property?

```
<option value="option2" selected>M</option>
```

Comment: Thank you. That was my first effort, but while it does change the value to "M", the BUY button remains corresponding to "S".

Answer (score 0):

You got 3 options

1.Using HTML `selected` property for the option you want.

```
<select id="selectMe">
    <option value="option1">S</option>
    <option value="option2" selected>M</option>
    <option value="option3">L</option>
</select>
```

2.Using jQuery

```
$('#selectMe').val('option2')
```

3.Using pure JS

```
document.getElementById('selectMe').value = 'option2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var options = $('#selectMe option');
var total = options.length + ((options.length % 2 == 0) ? 0 : -1);
var value = $(options[total / 2]).val();
$('#selectMe').val(value);
```

Comment: Thank you. This works in part -- but, in this instance, when the page is loaded, "M" is in the dropbown, but "Button for size S" (to reference the question) is still displayed.

Comment: Why a button for each option? Could you handle a single button which you modified its label, according to the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

Try with one button:

HTML:

```
<select id="selectMe">
<option value="option1">S</option>
<option value="option2">M</option>
<option value="option3">L</option>
</select>
...
<div>
<div id="button-size" class="group">Button for size S</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var options = $('#selectMe option');
var total = options.length + ((options.length % 2 == 0) ? 0 : -1);
var value = $(options[total / 2]).val();
$('#selectMe').val(value);
changeButtonLabel(value);

$('#selectMe').on('change', function (evt)
{
    var value = $(this).val();
    changeButtonLabel(value);
});

function changeButtonLabel(value)
{
 $('#button-size').html('Button for size ' + $('#selectMe').find('option[value=' + value + ']').html());
}
```